# When using a handler how do I write a log once per rountrip?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ive written a http handler to plug into our sites that I want to be able to write the

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
```

to a table only once per rountrip for basically page logging.

The full code is:

```
    void context_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Will avoid the scenario where session has not been instantiated
        //on W3SVC restart
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {

                WebLogging weblogger = new WebLogging();

                if (HttpContext.Current.Session[EnumsAndConstants.Keys.UserId] != null)
                {
                    weblogger.UserId = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session[EnumsAndConstants.Keys.UserId];
                }

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                {
                    weblogger.UrlReferrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
                }

                //Will always have a value
                weblogger.RequestType = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestType;

                statisticsManager.CreateWebLogging(weblogger);

        }

    }
```

This seems to write a log for the page and every control per roundtrip as im getting multiple logs.

So how can I modify the code to only happen once per roundtrip.

I have to use a http module for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully someone else will answer if there is a more definitive way, but I don't believe there is any one thing you can easily check to get what you want.

You say you want to log "once per roundtrip", you are pretty much doing that now.  When a browser requests a URL, it receives an HTML response from the server.  As the browser goes to render that page, it will come across external resources that it needs (images, stylesheets, javascript files, etc).  For each one of these, it must make another request to the server to get it.  This is why you are logging so many requests, because you are logging one for each.

One thing you can look at to cut down on the noise (assuming you aren't interested when a browser requests the resource files) is to look at the following property:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension
```

This will get you the file extension of the current request (assuming there is one, if there isn't, it looks like it uses an empty string).  So you can add a filtering mechanism to the module to filter out a certain set of extensions (.jgp, .gif, .png, .js, .css, etc).